# NPM downloadable package with only high level brand styles

Tags: ui, npm

I've been tasked to create an NPM package that our Frontend teams can make use of that has styling for the companys UI elements:

- Layout Grid unit proportions, gutters and spacing.

  Typography Headings, body text, links, lists, inset text, hidden
  text.

  Colour Colour contrast, Sass variables, colour palettes.

  Icons and images Icons and image ratios.

  Data Data in a table, numeric tabular data, data visualisation.

  Buttons Button text, button alignment, creating buttons.

  Form elements Form fields, labels, focus states, radio buttons,
  checkboxes.

  Errors and validation Summary boxes, highlighting errors in forms.

Has anyone come across something similar and can point me to examples of how it has been done. Does it seem like a viable project to undertake?

Answer (score -1):

There are *many* examples of this, not the least of which is [Bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap), one of the most widely used CSS frameworks out there.  It's definitely a good idea, and I'd go one further and suggest you make a simple site demonstrating all the features, like [Foundation's Kitchen Sink Demo](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/kitchen_sink.html).  As a sidenote, Foundation *also* has an npm package.